# MySQL - Group by case of count

Tags: mysql

My MySQL query is :

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN count(`image`.`context_uuid`) = 0 THEN 'No image' 
    WHEN count(`image`.`context_uuid`) = 1 THEN '1 image' 
    WHEN count(`image`.`context_uuid`) = 2 THEN '2 images' 
    WHEN count(`image`.`context_uuid`) = 3 THEN '3 images' ELSE '4 and + images' 
END AS `Informations`, count(`exchange_product`.`exchange_product_id`) AS `total`
FROM `exchange_product`
INNER JOIN `product` ON `product`.`product_id` = `exchange_product`.`product_id`
INNER JOIN `image` ON `image`.`context_uuid` = `product`.`product_uuid`
GROUP BY 
CASE 
    WHEN count(`image`.`context_uuid`) = 0 THEN 'No image' 
    WHEN count(`image`.`context_uuid`) = 1 THEN '1 image' 
    WHEN count(`image`.`context_uuid`) = 2 THEN '2 images' 
    WHEN count(`image`.`context_uuid`) = 3 THEN '3 images' ELSE '4 and + images' 
END
```

In my DB, I have a table :

image

```
| image ID     | url         | context_type | context_uuid  |
|--------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
| 1            | www.az.com  | user         | 19            |
| 2            | www.az.com  | product      | 27            |
| 3            | www.az.com  | product      | 27            |
| 4            | www.az.com  | product      | 28            |
```

exchange_product

```
| exchange_product_id | owner_id | product_id | receiver_id |
|---------------------|----------|------------|-------------|
| 1                   | 23       | 27         | 19          |
| 2                   | 38       | 28         | 19          |
| 3                   | 94       | 92         | 90          |
```

product

```
| product_id   | user_id     | name       | product_uuid |
|--------------|-------------|------------|--------------|
| 1            | 23          | something  | 28           |
| 2            | 38          | something  | 12           |
| 3            | 94          | something  | 23           |
```

I want to have a result like this but I can't group by count of image...

```
| Informations | total |
|--------------|-------|
| No image     | 2563  |
| 1 image      | 1029  |
| 2 images     | 567   |
| 3 images     | 180   |
| 4 + images   | 1928  |
```

I want to know the count of exchanges of product that have :

- 0 image
- 1 image
- 2 images
- 3 images
- 4+ images

My current output when I GROUP BY image.context_uuid is :

```
| Informations | total |
|--------------|-------|
| No image     | 2563  |
| 1 image      | 1     |
| 1 image      | 3     |
| 1 image      | 1     |
| 1 image      | 2     |
```

Comment: What is your current query's output ?

Comment: What should the expected output be based on the example data?

Comment: Hint: use `left join`. First count images for every specific exchange_product_id (`group by exchange_product_id`). Now use this result set as a Derived table and then count number of exchange_product_id(s) with 0 image, 1 image and so on.

Comment: Current output is an error because I can't make a count in WHERE

Comment: I added the output when I group by image.context_uuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `Left Join` on `image` table, in order to consider those cases also, where there is no image (no matching row).
- You need to first count the number of images for every `product_id` specifically.
- Now, use these count results as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and `Count` the product_id(s) depending on which category they lie in ('No image' to '4 and + images')
- Note that [in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html), the Alias defined in the `Select` clause can be used as it is, in the `Group By`, `Having` and `Order By` clauses.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN dt.images_count = 0 THEN 'No image' 
    WHEN dt.images_count = 1 THEN '1 image' 
    WHEN dt.images_count = 2 THEN '2 images' 
    WHEN dt.images_count = 3 THEN '3 images' 
    ELSE '4 and + images' 
  END AS `Informations`, 

  COUNT(dt.product_id) AS `total` 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    `exchange_product`.`product_id`, 
    COUNT(`image`.`context_uuid`) AS images_count 
  FROM `exchange_product`
  LEFT JOIN `product` ON `product`.`product_id` = `exchange_product`.`product_id`
  LEFT JOIN `image` ON `image`.`context_uuid` = `product`.`product_uuid`
  GROUP BY 
    `exchange_product`.`product_id`
) AS dt 
GROUP BY `Informations`
```

Comment: Ok I need to check if I have an exchange with 2 images or more because the result of this query is : 1 image -> 1300 /// No image -> 4067

Comment: There is no 2 images or 3 images results

Comment: @ThibC. your database has cases with 2 images or 3 images ?

Comment: Yes I have some exchanges with product that have 2 images

Comment: @ThibC. do these product_id(s) have entry in all the three tables ?

Comment: @ThibC. check the updated answer. I removed `Distinct` in count and change another join to `left join` as well.

Comment: @ThibC. happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an inline view (derived table) to get a count of images for each product_id. (Run  the query inside the parens to see the result that is returned. That should be each distinct product_id, with the funky count of images related to the product.

Join the result of the inline view to the `exchange_product` table. And the outer query, we can do the GROUP BY on the funky count.

```
SELECT q.image_cnt                          AS `Informations`
     , COUNT(e.product_id)                  AS `total`
  FROM ( -- count of images by product_id
         SELECT p.product_id
              , CASE COUNT(i.context_uuid)
                WHEN 0 THEN 'No image'
                WHEN 1 THEN '1 image'
                WHEN 2 THEN '2 images'
                WHEN 3 THEN '3 images'
                ELSE '4 and + images'
                END AS image_cnt
           FROM `product` p
           LEFT
           JOIN `image` i
             ON i.context_uuid = p.product_uuid
          GROUP
             BY p.product_id
       ) q
  JOIN `exchange_product` e
    ON e.product_id = q.product_id
 GROUP
    BY q.image_cnt
 ORDER
    BY q.image_cnt+0
```